# Multiple conditions in while; second condition never applies

Tags: java

I have a compound statement as follows:

```
for (int count = 0; count <= passLength; count++)
{            
    while( !(charGenerator >= 65 && charGenerator <= 90) || (charGenerator >= 97 && charGenerator <= 122))
    {
        charGenerator = randNum.nextInt(123);
    }
    System.out.print((char)charGenerator);
    charGenerator = 0;
}
```

I have it within the for loop so it will generate many numbers at once, but my problem is it never picks numbers within the second range, in other words I never get any numbers from 97 to 122. It works fine with the first range. How do I make it so that it chooses random number from both groups?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `<joke>`That's the problem with random number generators: you can never be sure!`</joke>`. In case you did not recognize the reference, here's the [link](http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Random%20Number%20Generator).

Comment: When I was testing it, I legitimately thought I was just getting really unlucky for the first few tests. Doh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `!` applies to the first term of the `||`, not to the entire expression. Add a pair of parentheses:

```
while( !((charGenerator >= 65 && charGenerator <= 90) ||
         (charGenerator >= 97 && charGenerator <= 122)) )
```